# Error in openni_grabber.cpp while installing ROS Groovy from source on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: pcl, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

When running the command `./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install` I get the following error:

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/7b5a9aed20274fa53774a1cc2568ba13

Any idea at all in what could be the problem in `openni_grabber.cpp`?

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/126846/error-in-openni_grabber.cpp-while-installing-ros-groovy-from-source-on-ubuntu-13.10/) by [TSC](https://answers.ros.org/users/8171/tsc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 180 on 2014-02-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems like you have a Eigen version installed that is too new for PCL. It seems in 3.2 the sqrt function moved from eigen::internal::sqrt to eigen::sqrt. See this question:

http://answers.ros.org/question/128916/ros-groovy-compile-fails-at-pcl/

So you could either try to change the source of PCL or make sure it is using eigen 3.1 to compile.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TSC](https://answers.ros.org/users/8171/tsc/) on 2014-02-17**:
I changed the question, cause the solution for the eigen.h error is given in this answer. But after that, It crashes in another error.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-02-17**:
How exactly did you change the eigen file? What version are you using? Can you try using a version of Eigen that is known to work with PCL, like 3.0.5 or 3.1.0 as suggested in the answer I linked? I dont know if the new error is due to Eigen, but it makes things easier to start with validated deps.

**Comment by [TSC](https://answers.ros.org/users/8171/tsc/) on 2014-02-17**:
What I did was changing Eigen::internal::sqrt to pcl::sqrt and Eigen::internal::sin/cos to sin/cos, as suggested in a related post here in the forum. Anyway, how can I change the version of Eigen?

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-02-17**:
Not sure. I'm on a Mac so I have a hard time testing this. I guess Eigen is system installed?